# Где хранится информация от типе данных указателя (переменной)?

Tags: c++, указатели

Указатель хранит адрес первого байта хранимых данных. Но также указатель "знает" о размере этой памяти и о том, как эти данные интерпретировать (хранит тип данных). Сам адрес, судя по всему, занимает 3 байта. Размер указателя - 4 байта. Отсюда мой вывод: информация о типе данных хранится в четвертом, скрытом байте. Этот байт либо перед адресом, либо после. Как получить и разобрать эту информацию без использования высокоуровневых функций?

Или информация о типах данных держится отдельно во время выполнения программы? И верно ли я понимаю, что сама по себе переменная и есть указатель? Ведь она так же хранит адрес, где лежат данные и тип этих данных. (Или у меня каша в голове...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 242304;

    cout << "Address of pointer to num (variable num): " << &num << endl;
    cout << "Size of pointer to num (variable num): " << sizeof(&num) << endl;
    cout << "Type of pointer to num (variable num): " << typeid(&num).name();
}

// Address of pointer to num (variable num): 0x61ff0c
// Size of pointer to num (variable num): 4
// Type of pointer to num (variable num): Pi
```

Comment: *"Но также указатель "знает" о размере этой памяти и о том, как эти данные интерпретировать (хранит тип данных)."* - ничего подобного. `sizeof` вычисляется на этапе компиляции (причем тут вычисляется размер указателя, а не размер объекта, на который тот указывает), так же как и typeid в данном случае.

Comment: в си и с++ информация о размере памяти хранится, но это детали менеджера памяти. Он в принципе может ничего и не хранить - его право. Считайте, что официально у Вас нет доступа к такой информации.

Comment: @KoVadim Ничего там не хранится, это же даже не динамически выделенная память.

Comment: `Но также указатель "знает" ...` Нет. Это _компилятор_ знает о типе/размере данных на которые указывает указатель. И когда вы работаете с указателем (например, пишите `*(ptr + 1)`), то компилятор просто генерирует процессорные инструкции соответствующие типу/размеру данных, на которые указывает указатель.

Comment: @wololo В общем случае ничего такого компилятор не знает. Следить за тем, чтобы динамический тип объекта был совместим со статическим типом указателя на этот объект - обязанность программиста.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как "знания" компилятора проявляются во время выполнения программы? И где эти знания хранятся? Они отделены от объектов и существуют отдельно?

Comment: Допустим вы написали: `int arr[5] = {}; int* ptr = &arr[0]; ptr = ptr + 1;` На сколько байт увеличится значение указателя `ptr` при выполнении строки `ptr = ptr + 1;`? На `sizeof(int)` (на практике обычно `4`) байт. В самом указателе `ptr` никакой дополнительной информации о том, что размер `int` равен `4` не хранится. Просто при компиляции компилятор посмотрел тип переменной `ptr` и написал соответствующие инструкции, чтобы указатель нарастился именно на четыре байта, а не какое-либо иное значение.

Comment: @wololo, кажется начинаю понимать. То есть, все инструкции по манипуляцией с памятью формируются на стадии компиляции, и компилятор в зависимости от среды выполнения сразу подставляет всю конкретику для таких инструкций. Я после JS не совсем еще втыкаю в саму идею компиляции, значит. То есть, все подобные данные зашиваются в инструкции во время компиляции? То есть, во время выполнения вне зависимости от поступаемых в программу данных никаких **новых** типов данных появиться не может?

Comment: Все-таки, как чисто технически можно исследовать эти четыре байта, выделенных на указатель? Я пытаюсь сформировать указатель типа char по этому же адресу чтобы перебрать потом этот кусок, но никак не получается. В куче может, alloc/malloc?

Comment: `То есть, все инструкции по манипуляцией с памятью формируются на стадии компиляции` Ну, в общем-то так и есть. НО есть и некоторые специфические исключения. Например, _иногда_ указатель всё-таки «знает» размер памяти, на которую он указывает. См.: [Откуда C/C++ знает сколько надо освободить памяти, если не знает размер массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796215). А иногда даже кое-что знает о реальном типе объекта, на который он указывает. См.: [В каких случаях использовать указатель на базовый класс, а в каких на наследник?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584008).

Comment: `Все-таки, как чисто технически можно исследовать эти четыре байта, выделенных на указатель?` Посмотрите [пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/979bfd7ff263398d).

Comment: @wololo, спасибо, круто! `reinterpret_cast` значит нужно было использовать. Почти все понятно, но однозначно ли надо понимать, что остальные байты - нулевые? Нулями эти части заполняются инструкциями `setfill(0)` и `std::setw(2)` (не один 0), видимо. Но в реальности же там мусор должен быть. Другими словами служебная там информация или мусор, но программа выводит нули, изменяя оригинальную память. Или быть того не может? Спасибо большое, было чему поучиться!

Comment: В приведённом примере указатель занимает восемь байт. И программа последовательно выводит значения каждого из восьми байт. Сперва от младшего к старшему, потом в обратном порядке. В приведённой программе диапазон значений, которые может принимать переменная типа `unsigned char` — целые числа из отрезка `[0; 255]`. Но выводятся они в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления (`cout << std::hex`), для каждого числа отводится по крайней мере два символа (`cout << std::setw(2)`), причём _если_ для отображения числа достаточно одного символа, то слева он дополняется нулями (`cout << std::setfill('0');`).

Comment: [Тот же самый пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e756d4afa56c69a5) но без всех украшательств. Байты выводятся через пробел в десятичной системе счисления без дополнения нулями. И да, по примеру видно, что некоторые из байтов, составляющих указатель, равны нулю. В этом нет ничего необычного. Никто не гарантирует, что все байты до единого, составляющие указатель, будут отличны от нуля.

Comment: Это все я понял. 0 же не абы где, а именно там, где в отведенной памяти нет полезной информации - как заполнители. Я предполагал, что программа игнорирует лишние байты в памяти во время записи и в них должен остаться мусор. А получается, что туда записываются 0х00 именно. Это познавательно. Все же есть подозрение, что туда вход закрыт и нам показываются 0))) Вроде: не лезь - здесь служебная информация))

Comment: Почему вы решили, что ноль находится там, где нет полезной информации? Все восемь байт участвуют в формировании значения указателя, включая нулевые.

Comment: `0x7fff9ec83704` - потому, что реальный адрес состоит всего из 6 байт. Остальные два как раз по моему подозрению скрытые или просто заполнены 0. Или имеется в виду, что так как они со старшей стороны, то просто опускаются при выводе? Понял, просто это можно рассмотреть как резерв для адресных значений или случайное совпадение, что за этот предел обычно не выходит, но адрес состоит именно что из 8 байт и не надо ничего выдумывать... Спасибо, понял!

Comment: `Или имеется в виду, что так как они со старшей стороны, то просто опускаются при выводе?` Да так и есть. Например, в таком коде `unsigned long long val = 1; cout << val;` будет просто напечатана единица без ведущих нулей, даже если `val` будет занимать целых восемь байт. Ну, если конечно не предпринять дополнительных усилий по форматированию вывода.

Comment: При старте программы в регистре `SP` хранится адрес стека. Каждый раз другой. И если запустить одновременно несколько экземпляров программы, то тоже у всех разные адреса. Компилятор назначает смещение для этой переменной, например ноль, и потом всегда пользуется так : `mov [SP + 0],242304` Смещение уже записано в программе компилятором, а фактический адрес хранится в `SP`.